# subcomponent failed in igraph

Tags: r, error-handling, social-networking, igraph

I have started exploring Stanford's [Social Network Analysis](http://sna.stanford.edu/lab.php?l=2) course and in the second lab, I bumped into a problem with the code provided.

It concerns the following function:

```
reachability <- function(g, m) {
  reach_mat = matrix(nrow = vcount(g), 
                     ncol = vcount(g))
  for (i in 1:vcount(g)) {
    reach_mat[i,] = 0
    this_node_reach <- subcomponent(g, (i - 1), mode = m)

    for (j in 1:(length(this_node_reach))) {
      alter = this_node_reach[j] + 1
      reach_mat[i, alter] = 1
    }
  }
  return(reach_mat)
}
```

Now, when applying this function to a graph object `krack_full` with following characteristics

```
summary(krack_full)
 IGRAPH DN-- 21 232 -- 
 + attr: name (v/c), AGE (v/n), TENURE (v/n), LEVEL (v/n), DEPT (v/n), color (v/c), frame (v/c), advice_tie (e/n), friendship_tie (e/n),| reports_to_tie (e/n), color (e/c), arrow.size (e/n)
```

the following error appears (via traceback)

```
 Error in .Call("R_igraph_subcomponent", graph, as.igraph.vs(graph, v) -  : 
  At structural_properties.c:1244 : subcomponent failed, Invalid vertex id 
3 .Call("R_igraph_subcomponent", graph, as.igraph.vs(graph, v) - 
    1, as.numeric(mode), PACKAGE = "igraph") 
2 subcomponent(g, (i - 1), mode = m) 
1 reachability(krack_full, "in")
```

You can get the exact data by running [lab 1](http://sna.stanford.edu/lab.php?l=1)

Any idea how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong indexing (R indexes are 1-based), this should be correct:

```
reachability <- function(g, m) {
  reach_mat = matrix(nrow = vcount(g), 
                     ncol = vcount(g))
  for (i in 1:vcount(g)) {
    reach_mat[i,] = 0
    this_node_reach <- subcomponent(g, i, mode = m) # used "i" instead of "(i - 1)"

    for (j in 1:(length(this_node_reach))) {
      alter = this_node_reach[j] # removed "+ 1"
      reach_mat[i, alter] = 1
    }
  }
  return(reach_mat)
}
```

BTW, I think you can get the same reachability matrix by doing :

```
# this returns the minimum distance between each node (=inf if not reachable)
distMatrix <- shortest.paths(krack_full, v=V(krack_full), to=V(krack_full))
# we set the values that are not infinite to 1
distMatrix[!is.infinite(distMatrix)] <- 1
# we set the values that are infinite to 0
distMatrix[is.infinite(distMatrix)] <- 0
# now distMatrix is your reachability matrix
```

Comment: That does seem to solve the problem indeed. I figured the minus 1 and plus 1 were because igraph indexes are zero-based unlike R. Perhaps that was the case in the past and they have changed that...

Comment: Yes, now that I think of it, in the past maybe igraph indexing was indeed `0-based`...mmh, this also means a lot of answers here are probably wrong now...let me check...

Comment: Found it. From version >= 0.6 igraph nodes indexing is 1-base : http://igraph.org/2012/06/11/igraph-0.6-r.html